# Powershell with WMI - IIS 6 Set .NET Runtime version

Tags: iis, powershell

Using WMI within a powershell script, how can I set the .NET runtime version of a virtual directory targetting IIS 6?  I want to be able to set it to use .NET 4.0.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update the [ScriptMaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525005%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Take a look at the [VBScript sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923/vbscript-iis-how-do-i-automatically-set-asp-net-version-for-a-particular-websit)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any access to my code from here, but ...

- Manually configure one site to the .NET 4.0 maps
- WMI get ScriptMaps from that virtual directory
- WMI get the virtual directory you'd like to update (iteratively)
- WMI set target.ScriptMaps = source.ScriptMaps
- Commit your changes.